# absolute to relative path conversion

Tags: excel, relative-path, absolute-path, wsh

This code snippet is working fine when the path is declared as absolute. Consider the line

```
var wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\\temp\\temp.csv");
```

in the code. However, I want to declare a relative path for the same. How do I do that?

```
var xl = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    xl.Visible = true;
    var wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\\temp\\temp.csv");
    var sheet = wb.ActiveSheet;

    wb.Worksheets.Add(after=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count));
    var pws = wb.ActiveSheet;
    pws.Name="temp_pivot";
    var pvtTable = pws.PivotTableWizard(1, varSource=wb.sheets("temp").Range("A1").CurrentRegion);
    pvtTable.PivotFields("DECISIONYEAR").Orientation = 1;
    pvtTable.PivotFields("DECISIONMONTH").Orientation = 1;
    pvtTable.PivotFields("WEEKYEAR").Orientation = 1;
    pvtTable.PivotFields("APPLICANT").Orientation = 4;
    pvtTable.PivotFields("SUM OF APPLICANT").Function=-4157;
    pvtTable.PivotFields("APPROVED").Orientation = 4;
    pvtTable.PivotFields("SUM OF APPROVED").Function=-4157;
    pvtTable.PivotFields("SOURCE").Orientation = 3;
    pvtTable.PivotFields("PRODUCTCOLOR").Orientation = 3;
    pvtTable.PivotFields("PRODUCT").Orientation = 3;
    pvtTable.PivotFields("SUB_CHANNEL_CADM").Orientation = 3;
    pvtTable.PivotFields("CHANNEL_CADM").Orientation = 3;
    pvtTable.PivotFields("MARKET").Orientation = 3;
    pvtTable.PivotFields("OFFER_TYPE").Orientation = 3;
    pvtTable.DataPivotField.Orientation=2;
    pws.Columns.Autofit;
    pws.Rows.Autofit;
    xl.DisplayAlerts =0;
    xl.DisplayAlerts = 1
    xl.CutCopyMode = 0;
    xl.EnableEvents = 0;
    xl = null;
```

Comment: Yes, its Windows Scripting Host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Scripting Host part of things lets you use paths relative to the current directory, which will be the directory where you launched the script. If you launch it from the command line, then of course it'll be your current directory in the command line. If you launch it by double-clicking the file in Windows Explorer, it'll be the directory in which you double-clicked it.

You can find out what the current directory is when you launch the file in various ways like this:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var curDir = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".");
WScript.Echo(curDir);
```

Excel, though, may not default to the same directory. (On my system, for instance, it defaults to the user's documents folder.) So you'll want to use `fso.GetAbsolutePathName` and then pass the absolute path to Excel, like this:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var xl = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
xl.Visible = true;
var wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(fso.GetAbsolutePathName("temp.csv"));
```

That way, although you're using a relative path in your code, you're passing an absolute path to Excel so it finds it regardless of what *it* thinks the current directory is.

Comment: I don't think this would help. Kindly help me in writing the syntax for relative path for the same. Thanks !

Comment: @user3444944: You just use the relative path, exactly like you would anywhere else. I was pointing out what it was relative **to**. If you're in `c:\temp` and you want to access `c:\temp\temp.csv`, the relative path is `temp.csv`. But if you're in (say) `c:\somewhere_else_completely`, then of course the relative path is `\temp\temp.csv`. If you're in `d:\yet_another_place` there there **is** no relative path to the file (er, barring command-line current directories on each drive), so you'd need `c:\temp\temp.csv`.

Comment: I tried using relative path just as you mentioned but it doesn't seem to work that way.What can be the alternate solution ?

Comment: @user3444944: Looks like Excel doesn't use the current directory. I've updated to show how to work around that.

Comment: Just 1 more question ! The excel sheet makes both the tabs viz temp_pivot and Temp visible. I want that the user just sees the temp_pivot. So I added the line Temp.Visible=False. But on doing so,It hides the temp_pivot tab and displays just the Temp tab. Now, how to rectify that ?

Comment: @user3444944: No idea, I suggest posting a separate question flagged with [tag:excel-automation].